# Delete option is grayed out in disk management (Windows 10) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am dual booting Ubuntu and I want to delete Ubuntu from my computer. In windows 10 disk management the option to delete the partition is grayed out. Does anyone have a solution to this?

[image: screenshot of Disk Management MMC snap-in in Windows]

Comment: We support Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu here. Since you don't want to use Ubuntu anymore; you delete it within your Windows 10 system, and have windows 10 take ownership of grub/booting (if Ubuntu handled that; otherwise you won't be able to reboot windows) - but this is now a Windows issue and off-topic here - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @guiverc Judging by [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on), we seem to support that Windows issue on AU at least to some extent. However, that's probably not the situation here. The partition the screenshot shows [is the optical drive with Ubuntu installation media in it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163475). So we *could* consider this off-topic after all...but personally I hope we keep it open. The confusion here can also occur as one prepares to *install* Ubuntu, a use case we support in greater depth.

Answer (score 3):

That would appear to be the Ubuntu install disk that is still in your DVD drive. Simply eject it.

Comment: No, I installed it through a bootable usb. I don't know why it shows it in there. I have one hard drive and I shrunk the windows partition to half the drive space and installed Ubuntu on the other half of the drive. I have no disk in my laptop.

Comment: Ok, this is more of a windows problem then. The size of the partition suggests it is install media, not an installation. I have seen Windows display a usb drive as a CD before so it could simply be your bootable usb still inserted. I’m not a Windows expert but I’d guess you can mount an image somehow. Perhaps it’s just a file on your file system that has been mounted. If none of this resolves your issue I suggest you try a Windows forum. Would be interested to hear what it is when you have fixed it.

Comment: Seems you can mount an image in Windows. To unmount it open file explorer. Right click your G: drive and click Eject. If this is the case there will be a 1.8G file somewhere to delete too.

Comment: It wasn't a bootable drive of any sort. It was installed a couple of weeks ago and I've been using it, no bootable drive in the computer at all. I don't understand why it showed up as a cd drive and not on the hard drive but I ended up ejecting it and it disappeared and that was it. I have no clue where it would have been installed on my computer because I only have one hard drive and that is the only kind of storage on my computer.

Comment: I have used Ubuntu while having nothing in the computer so the only explanation is that it was running on the hard drive. I searched my entire drive for Ubuntu and nothing came up so I assume it's gone but I don't know for sure. I guess I solved my question but now I'm quite curious where Ubuntu was installed. Thanks for the help though, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think about how it was labeled as cd/rom so I right clicked on it and selected eject which seemed to do the trick.